# VueJS spa .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out what my .htaccess file needs to look like. I'm running a SPA VueJS app on a separate https domain from my api.

I seem to have it sort of working with my rules below, but its not excluding the /static folder, so none of my assets (fonts, css, etc) is getting loaded properly.

I can't seem to find a decent example on Google or SO that matches my setup (https SPA with api and app on separate domains).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-vue-domain.com/$1 [R]

    RewriteRule ^(static) - [L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If e.g. `/static/js/app.js` is real file in your Document root, you do not need to exclude it at all because you did exclude all files and folders with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I would remove :

```
RewriteRule ^(static) - [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
```